# How do remove/Destroy a b2Body with a selector?

Tags: box2d, box2d-iphone

I am trying to remove a b2Body with a selector after creating it.
It is not work with the following code.
Please give me a hint.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(removeBox:) withObject: body afterDelay:2];
```

Here is the error message:
Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id' with an lvalue of type 'b2Body *'

Note:
I used Box2d template and try to remove a box after creating it.

Thanks.

Comment: hi, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score -1):

Anything that changes the world state should not be done during a world step. According to the [iforce2](http://iforce2d.net/b2dtut/removing-bodies) tuto :

> One simple method for implementing a 'timed removal', that is for
>   example if you want to wait a certain time before deleting something,
>   is just to calculate how many time steps that would be for your game
>   loop (eg. 2 seconds is 120 time steps at 60fps), set that value in the
>   entity and then decrement it every frame until it gets to zero, then
>   remove it.

hope this will help.